# Writing to a 8 bit grayscale image in C#

Tags: c#-2.0, bitmap

I am building an application in C# and .NET 2.0 which takes an 8 bit grayscale image as input, does some operation on the pixel values and writes back to the image. When I write the pixel values back to the bitmap, the image is being displayed in color. Please help me fix this problem.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicate the gray value across all three channels.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if 8-bit grayscale is supported. You simulate it by using an 8 bit palette, with each color in the palette being a shade of gray.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I figured out that I need to take help of color palette and all. For now, I created a new 24bit bitmap and wrote the values into it and its working fine.

Thanks,
Rakesh.